# How to PUT data to JSON-Server when using URL parameters?

Tags: node.js, json, request, put, json-server

**db.json example:**

```
{
"articles":[{"art_id":1,"cat_id":1,"article":"Communication Device","description":"Small communication device in the shape of a pencil.","price":49.9900,"instock":25}],
"customers":[{"cust_id":1,"lastname":"De Vlieger","firstname":"Mehdi","city":"Bruges","birthdate":"1990-05-30"}]
}
```

**Request example:**

PUT: http://localhost:3000/articles?article=Communication%20Device

BODY:
*To change the price*

```
{
        "art_id": 1,
        "cat_id": 1,
        "article": "Communication Device",
        "description": "Small communication device in the shape of a pencil.",
        "price": 39.99,
        "instock": 25
}
```

RESPONSE: *404 Not Found*

Comment: Can you add the api code that accepts this?

Comment: It is made withe JSON-server so just the main function that takse the json file and truns it into a REST api

Comment: json-server requires you to be using the keyword "id" rather than "art_id", PUT requests also don't do anything unless they are PUT http://localhost:3000/articles/1